# Trouble with Visual Studio 2013 oracle database project

Tags: oracle, database-project

I'm having trouble adding tables to an oracle database project in Visual studio 2013. Some tables were able to be added, others are not. When I right click on the table in the server explorer then select "Generate create script to project" a window pops up saying the script is being generated but the script is never added. The only difference I see between the tables that work and those that don't is that the ones that don't are in a separate tablespace from the ones that work.

Comment: Having similar issue over here, I know it's old, but did you ever resolve this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35010961/oracle-developer-tools-odt-visual-studio-integration