# Oracle Developer Tools (ODT) & Visual Studio Integration

Tags: oracle

I've installed the ODT for Visual Studio 2015 (I've also tried VS2013) in hopes of using the "Oracle Database Project" but experiencing some specific error messages that don't appear to be very common.

When I browse the database via the Server Explorer, there is an option for you to be able to right click on a Relational Table and click "Generate Create Script to Project...".

However, when clicking this option I get a very non-specific error message and cannot work out why;

"Create script was not generated to Project  for some of the selected object(s).  See the 'Oracle Database Output' output pane for more information."

When I look at the "Oracle Database Output" window I get the message;

"Script Generation failed - Internal Error."

For here-on-in, it's gets very frustrating to find out what's wrong and to debug this non-descriptive error message.

What's most interesting is that the script generation function works for other database objects such as views & procedures, it just fails to work for database tables.

Has anybody experienced this error before?  I'm wondering if it's a driver issue of some sort!  (I have the oracle 11g client installed, and just tried with a specific ODAC/ODT combination package which appears to also install the 12c client, connecting to an Oracle Elements 11g server)

Any help appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: what version of oracle are you connecting to?  Can you connect to Oracle from Visual Studio?

Comment: Oracle 11g elements server.  The VS server browser for the database works, all the objects are visible and the SQL query executer works too,

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?  I am encountering the same issue.

Comment: Hi, afraid not.  It's a really frustrating one too, error messages are next to useless to find out why.  I suspect this project type isn't used that much, rather than just being a relatively unusual problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem too.

I was able to Create the scripts earlier, but now I cannot.

I did some investigating and decided this is not a problem with the oracle database. It is something to do with the state of VS.

I restarted VS2015 and I could create scripts again.